# Graphics getting drawn incorrectly in c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, zooming

How do I make sure my graphics are drawn in the right position? I have a windows form project where the user draws lines on an Image in a pictureBox (on top of a panel). When the picture box is in default zoom the lines are drawn correctly, and they respond correctly to the Image being ragged around. However when I try to draw on the image while zoomed in/out the position of line is offset (up and to left when zoomed out, down and right when zoomed in). The pictureBox and panel are anchored on all four sides and not docked. I tried using the TranslateTransform( dx, dy ) method but it didn't work. I also tried getting rid of my CenterBox() method. How do i proceed?

Here is code for zooming:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)  // zoom scale
{
    zoom = (float)(0.25 + 0.25 * (trackBar1.Value - 1));
    if (trackBar1.Value > 0)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = PictureBoxZoom(imgOriginal, new Size(trackBar1.Value, trackBar1.Value));
    }

}

public Image PictureBoxZoom(Image img, Size size) //creates zoomed in clone of user image
{
    sizeNewx = (Int32) (img.Width * zoom);
    sizeNewy = (Int32) (img.Height * zoom);
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(img, sizeNewx,sizeNewy);
    Graphics grap = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
    grap.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    CenterBox(pictureBox1, bm);
    return bm;
}

private void CenterBox(PictureBox picBox, Bitmap pic)
{
    picBox.Image = pic;
    picBox.Location = new Point((picBox.Parent.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (pic.Width / 2),
                       (picBox.Parent.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (pic.Height / 2));
    picBox.Refresh();
}
```

Here is how graphics are drawn and zoomed:

```
private Stack<Line> lines = new Stack<Line>();

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) //click in box
{
    var mouseEventArgs2 = e as MouseEventArgs;

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {        
        lines.Push(new Line { Start = mouseEventArgs2.Location });
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{       
    if (lines.Count > 0 && e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        lines.Peek().End = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoom, zoom);

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Pen magenta = new Pen(Color.Magenta, 2);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(magenta, line.Start, line.End);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cause the picbox is in zoom mode it does also scale your image proportionally to fit inside. That might be the issue. In `pictureBox1_Paint` you need to evaluate this scaling also. I haven't tested it so it is just an idea.

Comment: i thought i had already applied the zoom to the graphics with e.Graphics.ScaleTransform () method

Comment: Is your picturebox sizemode zoom? How do you declare `Line` structure? What is the start value of zoom? What is the range of `trackBar1`?

Comment: I used a constructor with Start {get; set;} and End{get; set;}. Also the trackbar is initiated to 4 making the zoom 1. Sorry for not putting the whole program, I was just showing the pertinent methods. The program is used to draw lines on an image as a means of measuring. Also the picture box is on top of a panel to accommodate images of any size.

Comment: You didnt say if your picturebox sizemode is zoom. So I assume it is which is wrong! Every time you scale the image it will scale back to the original size. If not then why do you move the picbox depending on the size? It doesn't make any sense. Picbox should remain still and use scrollbars to show the image. But picbox doesnt autoscroll so it is better to use the panel instead. That is my opinion.

Comment: I don't have the program with me but I'm not sure it was  zoom, I think it was auto. The picbox was more mobile so the user could make measurements across the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the issue. The problem is that the points you get in `mouse move` and `mouse end` are basically **scaled**, cause image is scaled and then in paint you scale them again. So you need to **un scale them** before paint:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) //click in box
{
    var mouseEventArgs2 = e as MouseEventArgs;

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {        
        Point[] pnts = new Point[ 1 ];
        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix( 1 / zoom, 0, 0, 1 / zoom, 0, 0 ); //un scale
        pnts[0]= mouseEventArgs2.Location;
        scaleMatrix.TransformPoints( pnts );

        lines.Push(new Line { Start = pnts[0] });
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{       
    if (lines.Count > 0 && e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Point[] pnts = new Point[ 1 ];
        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix( 1 / zoom, 0, 0, 1 / zoom, 0, 0 ); //un scale
        pnts[0]= e.Location;
        scaleMatrix.TransformPoints( pnts );

        lines.Peek().End = pnts[0];
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε. Clever user name BTW